# React native is not creating the link properly for searching

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am performing the search functionality in react native but i am getting an issue with sending the array of locations in link. My link is looking like this...

```
https://....listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=search&location=australia,england,united-emirates,united-kingdom
```

This is what i am getting comma seprated values in my link but i need this type of URL..

```
http://...search-freelancers/?keyword=&location%5B%5D=australia&location%5B%5D=canada
```

In this URL i have Array of locations i don't want comma separated values i need URL like this... here is my code where i am passing array in my URL...

```
fetchFreelancerData = async () => {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const response = await fetch(
        BaseUrl+"listing/get_freelancers? 
        listing_type=search&location="+params.projectLocationKnown 
        );
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });
        console.log( params.projectLocationKnown );
        console.log(    BaseUrl+"listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=search&profile_id=&keyword="+params.title+"&skills="+params.SkillsKnown+"&location="+params.projectLocationKnown+"&type="+params.freelancerLevelKnown+"&english_level="+params.englishKnown+"&language="+params.LangKnown  );
      };
```

In this patch of code i am getting values from another component and passing these array values in my fetch call here... please help about how to make the URL properly to fetch response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `encodeURIComponent(url)` where url is the string containing the url you need to convert